# Why wont my While work when i use a variable in my mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I've got the php script but it doesn't seem to run the while on it.

It's always worked before but today it didn't work.

```
include('../conect_to_myspl.php');
$email  = $_GET['e'];
$password = $_GET['p'];
$remember = $_GET['r'];
$selectEmail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectEmail)){

 $passowrdFromDB = $row['password'];
 $username = $row['username'];
 if($passowrdFromDB == $password){
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
 echo 1 ;
 }else{
 echo 0 ;
 }
 }
```

Comment: `if(!selectFoo){ echo "No result, or wrong query."; }`

Comment: is there an email "foo" in your database?

Comment: yes there is a foo in my database

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL);  
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and use `var_dump();` try `mysql_fetch_array` instead.

Comment: Don't expect anything to come of this, you're assigning `$row` and expect it to echo `yay`? You need to do `if(!$selectFoo){echo $row['email'];}` you need to check if there is a successful query, then if so, echo it.

Comment: what @Fred-ii- said, except with `$`: `if(!$selectFoo){echo $row['email'];}`

Comment: Oops, I forgot the `$` in there. Corrected. Thanks for catching that @joseph4tw +1

Comment: Then why not show us what you're actually using? I didn't post an "answer" because of **it**. See the answer already given below.

Comment: @randomsoupdog Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beginning of the PHP file to print the error.

Comment: what happens if you add `if(!$selectEmail){echo 'no data!;}` before the while loop? like @Fred-ii- recommended?

Comment: and check your `$_GET` as well

Comment: i only get "Deprecated :  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in "

Comment: Actually scratch my comment about *"mysql_fetch_array instead of mysql_fetch_assoc"* --- there's nothing wrong with your code. Make sure that you've selected the correct DB/table/columns and no typos and that there is in fact matching data in your DB.

Comment: *"i only get "Deprecated : mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in ""* Ah, your DB connection is `mysqli_*` right? @randomsoupdog I'll bet my last dollar on it. Change all instances of `mysql_` to `mysqli_`

Comment: yeah it is ,but when i change it (all of my mysql_) to mysqi_ it give me this error " mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given"

Comment: See my answer below, which I tested your code with an existing and similar DB I keep on my server. @randomsoupdog

Comment: *"yeah it is ,but when i change it (all of my mysql_) to mysqi_ it give me this error " mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given""* you're still using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` those two APIs do **NOT** mix. Everywhere where it says `mysql_` MUST be changed to `mysqli_` notice the `i`? @randomsoupdog use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

Comment: yes i have changed it but i get no output

Answer (score 1):

> *"i only get "Deprecated : mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in "*

I'm willing to bet my last dollar that your DB connection is `mysqli_*` and not `mysql_*` based. Yet, if it is `mysql_` then you need to change that to `mysqli_` see my example test that follows.

Change all instances of `mysql_` to `mysqli_` and add `$con` before `SELECT` or whatever variable you are using for DB connection in your connect file.

Assuming DB connection variable is `$con` (tested with a similar DB I already have on my server).

```
include('../conect_to_myspl.php');
$email  = $_GET['e'];
$password = $_GET['p'];
$remember = $_GET['r'];
$selectEmail = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectEmail)){

 $passowrdFromDB = $row['password'];
 $username = $row['username'];
 if($passowrdFromDB == $password){
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
 echo 1 ;
 }else{
 echo 0 ;
 }
 }
```

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s)

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);  
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

---

This is the code I tested with, using all `mysqli_*` functions for connection and query.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

/*
$email  = $_GET['e'];
$password = $_GET['p'];
$remember = $_GET['r'];
$selectEmail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectEmail)){

 $passowrdFromDB = $row['password'];
 $username = $row['username'];
 if($passowrdFromDB == $password){
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
 echo 1 ;
 }else{
 echo 0 ;
 }
 }
*/

$DB_HOST = "xxx";
$DB_NAME = "xxx";
$DB_PASS = "xxx";
$DB_USER = "xxx";

$db = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($db->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect [' . $db->connect_errno . ']');
}

$email  = "user1";
$password = "123";
// $remember = $_GET['r'];
$selectEmail = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectEmail)){

 $passowrdFromDB = $row['password'];
 $username = $row['username'];
 if($passowrdFromDB == $password){
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
 echo 1 ;
 }else{
 echo 0 ;
 }
 }
```

---

> *"yeah it is ,but when i change it (all of my mysql_) to mysqi_ it give me this error " mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given""*

You're still using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` those two APIs do **NOT** mix. Everywhere where it says `mysql_` MUST be changed to `mysqli_` notice the `i`? Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

---

Sidenote: Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) functions. (which I recommend you use and with [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo))

Comment: well you where correct in that i used mysql_. but i used your code (and changed the details to my database ect )but i still dont get outputted any thing

Comment: It seems obvious that whatever details are entered in your form or what you're using to pass through the GETs, isn't one that exists. Try using actuals instead of the variables. I.e.: `$email="email@example.com; $password="123";` @randomsoupdog and do `var_dump($_GET['e']);` and `var_dump($_GET['p']);` see what results you get.

Comment: Plus, my working example that I tested with, had `WHERE username='$email'")` I changed it to `WHERE email='$email'")` to reflect your DB and `members` instead of `users` for the table. Reload it and try it again @randomsoupdog

Comment: Done what you've said but still no output

Comment: What did `var_dump();` results give you? @randomsoupdog

Comment: Plus, are you sure you're using `$passowrdFromDB` and not `$passwordFromDB` as your variable? You realize you have a typo, so I have to assume any possible reasons. @randomsoupdog plus did you try the hard code method as I asked earlier? column types will matter also.

Comment: Another factor that could be at play here is that your form elements are not named. Do you have them named as `name="e"` and `name="p"` and `name="r"` in your form and is your form a POST method or GET? @randomsoupdog Post your form then.

Comment: in not using a form i'm using ajax and passing the variables as parameters on the url

Comment: Seems like it's your Ajax that's failing then. Try my code without Ajax and hard code the username/password variables in, and I will guarantee you, it's going to work. @randomsoupdog I won't be able to help you with the Ajax though, I know next to nothing about that.

Comment: Food for thought: When you have a question with a problem that consists of multiple codes PHP/SQL/JS/Ajax, post all of it. This will leave the guesswork out of it for others including myself. Many times it's one or a mix of other codes that are at fault. @randomsoupdog

Comment: Post your FULL code in your question and then edit your tags and add `ajax` to what you presently have in your tagging options. @randomsoupdog

Comment: well i have been running off not off ajax for the last thew test and when i put an echo out side off the wile(){} it does echo it and on to the ajax but here is the ajax:"jQuery.ajax({url:"./includes/login.php?e="+emailSign+"&p="+SignPass+"&r="+rememberSign,success:function(result){
  console.log(result);}"

Comment: @randomsoupdog As I mentioned earlier, I won't be able to help you with the Ajax part of it. Post all that in your question and re-tag. Someone may pick up on it and provide an additional or alternate answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$foo="foo";
$selectFoo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string($foo)."'");
if($error = mysql_error()) die("Got an error: ".$error);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectFoo)){
    echo 'yay';
}
```

I have sanitized the input string and used the [mysql_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) function to further investigate on the problem. Try this way.

However, you should switch to [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) since the mysql extension will be removed in the future.

Comment: or even better, pdo :)

Comment: yeah, ive add this but it still doesn't work, i also did try changing all the mysql to mysqli but still no success

Comment: do you get any output?

Comment: No i don't get an output